# Very large loss

Tags: keras

I tried to make a model that predicts the result of this function: $f(x,y,z)=x^{2}-y-2z$,
I made a lot of models but every time I get very large loss and a null accuracy 
.This is one of them :

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 3)                 12        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 128)               512       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65        
=================================================================
Total params: 8,845
Trainable params: 8,839
Non-trainable params: 6
_________________________________________________________________
```

This is the result :

```
Epoch 1/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 35ms/step - loss: 289500.5312 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 25271844.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 42ms/step - loss: 149032.7031 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 8126213.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 296302.0938 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 24036896.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 35ms/step - loss: 146951.5156 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 8174642.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 37ms/step - loss: 301296.7188 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 24906156.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 44ms/step - loss: 156428.3281 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7603723.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 44ms/step - loss: 308930.8438 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 22113846.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 37ms/step - loss: 142642.0000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 8524015.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 280426.1562 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 24125260.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 40ms/step - loss: 144546.4219 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 6978445.5000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 35ms/step - loss: 281056.4688 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 21430474.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 12/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 154448.0781 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7923529.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 13/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 48ms/step - loss: 315852.1562 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 22237864.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 14/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step - loss: 133407.5781 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7474352.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 15/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 38ms/step - loss: 254810.7500 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 21300726.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f29da312128>
```

What kind of mistakes did I make?

Comment: I am assuming you sample for X number of the data points given the function by changing x, y and z, right? How much data points you have? And it seems to be a function (would be better if you plot the function in 3D) with lots of local min and max. And the NN architecture seems to be very simple and might be incapable of estimating the function..Just sharing ideas here..

Comment: 8000 parm seems too much. Make your model very simple 10-20 parms. Else you will need much more data and epochs.